# SinglyLinkedList implementation with rule of 3

Tags: c++

I'm new to C++ and have been trying to implement a Singly Linked List, that provides an implementation the destructor, copy constructor and assignment operator. I'm running into compilation issues when trying to implement the copy constructor and the assignment operator.

Here's **node.hpp**

```
#ifndef LINKED_LIST_NODE_HPP
#define LINKED_LIST_NODE_HPP

template <typename T>
class Node{
public:
    T data;
    Node* next;
    Node();
    Node(T);
    Node(const Node&);
    ~Node();

};

template <typename T>
Node<T>::Node(){}

template <typename T>
Node<T>:: Node(const T data): data(data), next(nullptr){}

template <typename T>
Node<T>::Node(const Node<T>& source) : data(source.data),
                         next(new Node)
{
  (*next) = *(source.next) ;
}

template <typename T>
Node<T>::~Node(){}


#endif //LINKED_LIST_NODE_HPP
```

This is **singly_linked_list.hpp**

```
#ifndef LINKED_LIST_SINGLYLINKEDLIST_HPP
#define LINKED_LIST_SINGLYLINKEDLIST_HPP

#include <iostream>
#include "node.hpp"

template <typename T>
class SinglyLinkedList {

private:
    Node<T>* head;
    std::size_t count;

public:
    SinglyLinkedList();
    SinglyLinkedList(const SinglyLinkedList& source);
    SinglyLinkedList& operator=(const SinglyLinkedList& source);
    ~SinglyLinkedList();
    void insert(T);
    void remove(T);
    bool isEmpty();
    int length();
    void print();

};

template <typename T>
SinglyLinkedList<T>::SinglyLinkedList() : head(nullptr), count(0){}

template <typename T>
template <typename T>
SinglyLinkedList<T>::SinglyLinkedList(const SinglyLinkedList& source){

    Node<T>* curr = source.head;

    while(curr != nullptr){
        Node<T>* p = new Node<T>;
        p->data = curr->data;
        curr = curr->next;

    }

}

//template <typename T>
//SinglyLinkedList<T>::SinglyLinkedList& operator=(const SinglyLinkedList<T>& source){
//    //not sure how to implment this.
//}

template <typename T>
SinglyLinkedList<T>::~SinglyLinkedList() {
    if(!isEmpty()){
        Node<T>* temp = head;
        Node<T>* prev = nullptr;
        while(temp->next != nullptr){
            prev = temp;
            temp = temp->next;
            delete prev;
        }
        delete temp;
    }
}

template <typename T>
bool SinglyLinkedList<T>::isEmpty() {
    return head == nullptr;
}

template <typename T>
void SinglyLinkedList<T>::insert(T item) {
    Node<T>* p = new Node<T>(item);
    p->next = head;
    head = p;
    count += 1;

}

template <typename T>
void SinglyLinkedList<T>::remove(T item) {
    bool present = false;
    if (head->data == item){
        Node<T>* temp = head;
        head = head->next;
        delete(temp);
        count -= 1;
        return;
    }
    Node<T>* temp = head;
    while (temp->next != nullptr){
        if (temp->next->data == item){
            Node<T>* removable = temp->next;
            temp->next = temp->next->next;
            delete(removable);
            present = true;
            count -= 1;
            break;
        } else{
            temp = temp->next;
        }
    }
    if(!present){
        throw std::invalid_argument("item not present in list");
    }
}

template <typename T>
int SinglyLinkedList<T>::length() {
    return count;
}

template <typename T>
void SinglyLinkedList<T>::print() {
    if(isEmpty()){
        throw std::invalid_argument("Can't print an empty list!");
    }
    Node<T>* temp = head;
    while(temp != nullptr){
        if(temp->next != nullptr){
            std::cout<<temp->data;
            std::cout<<"->";
        }else{
            std::cout<<temp->data;
        }
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    std::cout<<std::endl;

}

#endif //LINKED_LIST_SINGLYLINKEDLIST_HPP
```

I've commented out the copy constructor code to make this compile. What is the correct way of doing this? I'm just learning C++.

Comment: Forget about your linked list template. Start by fixing `Node`'s copy constructor. It's broken. Before even getting around to the main linked list structure, you need to make sure that your `Node` template works correctly, otherwise it's a waste of time. You're not going to accomplish much with the approach of "write a massive pile of code and only then try to make it work". Professional C++ developers don't write code like that. They write a few lines of code, or a small part of a class first. Test it. Makes sure it works. Then write more code. You should fix your `Node`, first.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I've edited the code to provide a slightly better implementation of the Node. The code compiles in my system, but as I said I'm new to C++ and not sure how to test the copy constructor and the assignment operator for the node and linked_list class. A little help here might get me going in the right direction.

Comment: Just use a `std::vector` already. Or a `std::list` or `std::forward_list` if you *really have to* (and don't care about the crappy performance of lists on modern computers). Don't reinvent the wheel.

Comment: @JesperJuhl learning data structures in a language isn't actually reinventing the wheel, but yet something people new to a language do everyday. A constructive help might be more useful here.

Comment: The copy constructor still looks wrong. A typical copy constructor just copies a single object. This one also allocates its `next` pointer, for some reason, and assigns it. What if this is the last node in the singly linked list. Its `next` pointer will be null, Hello null pointer dereference, and an immediate crash! I think the best course of action here is to step back, take a blank sheet of paper, and write down a clear plan of action, specifying what each class, and each class method should be doing, and how it fits all together, before attempting to write even one more line of code.

Comment: *"not sure how to test the copy constructor and the assignment operator for the node"* You could start with something like this: https://wandbox.org/permlink/ChyPpIggt4dPHH8N

Comment: @Melissa Stewart - and I *might* provide more in an actual answer (or not), but the above was just a *comment*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't like the direction this is headed. I'm going to explain how to do this approach right because it is an excellent lesson on recursion, but because it's recursion it can run the program out of Automatic storage (march off the end of the stack, most likely) with a sufficiently large list. Not cool.

The logic:

Copying a node copies the next node if there is one. This looks something like

```
template <typename T>
Node<T>::Node(const Node<T>& source) : data(source.data)
{
    if (source.next) // if there is a next, clone it
    {
        next = new Node<T>(*source.next);
    }
    else
    {
        next = nullptr;
    }
}
```

This reduces the linked list copy constructor to

```
template <typename T>
SinglyLinkedList<T>::SinglyLinkedList(const SinglyLinkedList& source){

    head = new Node<T>(*source.head); //clone the head. Cloning the head will clone everything after
    count = source.count;
}
```

A helper function may, uh... help here to make the `Node` copy constructor a bit more idiomatic

```
template <typename T>
Node<T> * initnext(const Node<T> & source)
{
    if (source.next)
    {
        return new Node<T>(*source.next);
    }
    else
    {
        return nullptr;
    }
}

template <typename T>
Node<T>::Node(const Node<T>& source) : data(source.data),
                         next(initnext(source))
{
}
```

but I don't think you gain much.

So... I don't like the above. What would I do instead? Something a lot like opetroch's solution above, but different enough that I'll write this up.

The node stays brutally stupid. As far as I'm concerned all a `Node` should ever know is how to store the payload and find other `Node`s. This means the linked list should do all of the heavy lifting.

Concept 1: `head` is nothing but a next pointer. Once you abstract away its differences, unimportant here, you can use it exactly the same way you would `next`.

Concept 2: If you only know where `next` points, you have to do a bunch of extra book-keeping to track the previous node to update it's next. But if you take advantage of the previous's `next` pointing to the current node, you can throw out even more code. By tracking the previous node's `next` you have all of the information you need.

Concept 3: If you keep a pointer to the previous node's `next`, you can update that previous node's `next` any time you want by dereferencing it.

```
template <typename T>
SinglyLinkedList<T>::SinglyLinkedList(const SinglyLinkedList& obj)
{
    Node<T>* tocopy = obj.head;  
    Node<T>** nextpp = &head; // head is a next. We are now pointing to a pointer to next
    while (tocopy) // keep looping until there is no next node to copy
    {
        *nextpp = new Node<T>(tocopy->data); // copy source and update destination's next
        nextpp = &(*nextpp)->next; // advance to point at the next of the node we just added
        tocopy= tocopy->next; // get next node to copy
    }
    count = obj.count;
}
```

Because this iterates rather than recurses it doesn't eat up Automatic storage (probably the stack) and can keep going until the cows come home.

This logic can also be applied to `remove`

```
template <typename T>
void SinglyLinkedList<T>::remove(T item) {
    Node<T>** temp = &head; //head is nothing but a next pointer.
                            // by pointing to where the next is, we don't
                            // need to track a previous or have special handling
                            // for the head node
    while (*temp){ // because we now have a pointer to a pointer, we need an
                   // extra dereference
        if ((*temp)->data == item){
            Node<T>* removable = *temp;
            *temp = (*temp)->next;
            delete(removable);
            count -= 1;
            return; // no need for any special magic. Just get out.
        } else{
            temp = &(*temp)->next; // update the pointer to the next
        }
    }
    // if we got here the node was not found.
    throw std::invalid_argument("item not present in list");
}
```

And following through on `head` is just a `next`, we can also gut the destructor:

```
template <typename T>
SinglyLinkedList<T>::~SinglyLinkedList() {
    while(head){ // if head null, list empty
        Node<T>* temp = head; // cache so we can delete
        head = head->next; // move head
        delete temp; //delete removed node
    }
}
```

Comment: Indeed your copy constructor is neat and more efficient. I didn't want to make things complex for the OP since she is new to c++ so I went for something naive but readable. Nice one anyway.

Comment: @opetroch Go with readable, you got that right. That's why I wnt through the recursive approach. It doesn't get easier than that. But if you hand the iterative version into a marker for an intro to data structures class and you probably get crapped on for copying. Which has me pitying the couple people in the class who know or figured out this trick already.  That said, once you work it out and start thinking in abstractions and indirection, the rest of the course gets a lot easier.

Answer (score 2):

One issue that introduces complexity is that it is not well defined what the copy constructor of a node should do? Should the `next` field of the copy point to the next of the original, or it should create a copy of the next and point to that? The former is inadequate and error-prone, the latter would recursively create a copy of the whole list, one node at a time. This will work for lists of small size but will cause stack overflow for lists with many elements due to the depth of the recursive calls.

So to keep things simple, I wouldn't bother with copy constructor of a node.

```
template <typename T>
class Node {
public:
    T data;
    Node* next = nullptr;

    Node() = default;
    Node(const Node&) = delete; // since copying is not well defined, make it impossible to copy a node.
};
```

Copying a list is a well defined operation, so implementing the copy constructor makes sense. A mistake with your current implementation is that you allocate a new node, only to leak it later (nothing keeps track of the newly allocated node p). What you need looks more like this:

```
template <typename T>
SinglyLinkedList<T>::SinglyLinkedList(const SinglyLinkedList<T>& source)
    : head(nullptr)
    , count(0)
{
    // deal with the trivial case of empty list
    if (source.head == nullptr)
        return;

    // deal with the case where count >= 1
    head = new Node<T>;
    head->data = source.head->data;
    head->next = nullptr;
    count = 1;

    Node<T>* lastCopied = source.head;  // last node to be copied
    Node<T>* lastAdded = head;         // last node to be added to the current list
    while (lastCopied->next != nullptr)
    {
        // create new node
        Node<T>* p = new Node<T>;
        p->data = lastCopied->next->data;
        p->next = nullptr;

        // link the newly created node to the last of the current list
        lastAdded->next = p;
        lastAdded = p;

        // advance lastCopied
        lastCopied = lastCopied->next;
        count++;
    }
}
```

Now regarding the assignment operator, luckily you can use the 'copy and swap' idiom that greatly simplifies things.

```
template <typename T>
SinglyLinkedList<T>& SinglyLinkedList<T>::operator =(SinglyLinkedList<T> source)  // note that you pass by value.
{
    std::swap(head, source.head);
    std::swap(count, source.count);
    return *this;
}
```

My answer would become too long if I tried to explain the copy and swap technique. It is a clever trick to write exception safe code and avoid duplication (implements assignment by using the copy ctor) at the same time. It is worth reading about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3279543/77944).

Btw, the declaration of your class should look like this

```
template <typename T>
class SinglyLinkedList 
{

private:
    Node<T>* head = nullptr;
    std::size_t count = 0;

public:
    SinglyLinkedList(const SinglyLinkedList& source);
    SinglyLinkedList& operator=(SinglyLinkedList source);
    // other members here...
};
```

PS. My code assumes you are using c++11 or a later standard.